# Zlib Compression Screwed Up Path to Files in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, zlib, wpmu

I'm running a multisite network on `Wordpress 3.6` with the W3 Super Cache plugin for performance. I'm on a virtual dedicated server, but the Wordpress dashboard started loading so painfully slow, it was excruciating.

So I did a quick search and found this ["handy" tip on WPMU](http://wpmu.org/dramatically-speed-up-wordpress-and-wpmu-load-times-with-this-simple-tip/). The author suggested that using `zlib compression` would speed up my load times x3. So I took the advice and pasted this snippet in the header of my theme:

```
<?php 
    ini_set(’zlib.output_compression’, ‘On’);
    ini_set(’zlib.output_compression_level’, ‘1′);
?>
```

Instead of "instantly seeing a huge performance improvement," it screwed up something with the `blogs.dir` and now all uploads and media are broken links. I removed the above PHP snippet, but the links are still dead. I looked in `.htaccess` and `wp-config` and didn't see anything input from zlib.

Can anyone help me find a solution to this problem?

Comment: F*kin amateurs, how do people post code with curly quotes as a "tip"? And tell people to use in the theme! Which theme did apply this, the one of the main site? Make sure your .htaccess is exactly as in `wp-admin/network/setup.php`. Also check the error logs of the server and [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Maybe new info comes up. This stuff is out my expertise, but anyone looking into it may find [this ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14730) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the W3 Super Cache files, you may be looking at an outdated cached copy. I am not familiar with that plugin, I use W3TC, but there should be some sort of "clear cache" option. Otherwise, deactivate it, and see what happens.

You could also try going to permalink settings, and saving them - that will rewrite your .htaccess file for you - unless your caching plugin is interfering.